# How to make the "code execution" waiting for the main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I need to achieve the following: animation starts, wait until it is finished and then continue with the code execution. The problem is how to "pause" the code execution while the main thread is running. `OnAnimationEnd()` methods are not suitable.

I can use `postDelayed(Runnable r, long milliseconds)` and to put all my code in the runnable, but I am not sure it is the best way to do this. Also tried with `thread.sleep()`, `this.wait()`, and another instance of thread with runnable `threadnew.sleep()`, but I don't see the desired behavior: it seems that wait and sleep stop the animation and the code execution, not just the code execution.

```
public boolean onLongClick (View v)
 {

    if((v==textView2)&&(androidturn == false)&&(animationongoing == false))
        {
            androidturn = true;
            animationongoing = true;
            L.startAnimation(inFromRightAnimation);
            L.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                L.clearAnimation();
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                params.gravity = 0x50;
                params.height =710;

                L.setLayoutParams(params); 
                //L.layout(0,top,800,bottom);
                animationongoing = false;
            }
        }, 500);

        //here I need to stop the code execution for 500ms for animation to finish


            imageButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
        imageButton1.playSoundEffect(0);
```

Comment: Why can't you use `OnAnimationEnd`?

Comment: OnAnimationEnd() method for AnimationListener is not working properly.I do not want to override the same method for View,I just need the most simpliest way to make the code to "wait" until thread is doing something.....

Comment: "is not working properly" is too vague.  I suggest you post your code, and explain exactly what happened, as well as what you want to happen.

Comment: I've updated the question with my code.After startAnimation i need to stop the code execution for the lifetime of the animation and then to continue with it.It happens:animation starts and the button background is drawn red ,while the animation is ongoing...

Answer (score 0):

try an AsyncTask
here's an example it won't block the ui thread

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         /*setProgressPercent(progress[0]);*/
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         /*  call continute method here  */
     }
 }
```

sr: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I have read this,but correct me if i am wrong - this is the way to run something in background - task going in parallel with the main thread.I am agree with you - it won't block the UI thread,but what about the "code execution"?Could you please update your answer for the specific situation:            layout.startAnimation(GoDown)//duration 500 ms                      - ? wait 500 ms? (Using AsyncTask)                                 layout.addView()....I am afraid that this AsyncTask will be runned in background and the next line will be executed immediatelly......

Answer (score 0):

Separate the part to run after into its own method, then call it immediately or in the callback as appropriate.

```
public boolean onLongClick (View v)
 {

    if((v==textView2)&&(androidturn == false)&&(animationongoing == false))
        {
            androidturn = true;
            animationongoing = true;
            inFromRightAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
            {
              // Other listeners omitted.
              public void onAnimationEnd(Animation anim) {
                L.clearAnimation();
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

                params.gravity = 0x50;
                params.height =710;

                L.setLayoutParams(params); 
                //L.layout(0,top,800,bottom);
                animationongoing = false;
                styleImageButton();
              }
            });
        L.startAnimation(inFromRightAnimation);
    }
    else
    {
        styleImageButton();
    }
}

private void styleImageButton()
{        
    imageButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Red);
    imageButton1.playSoundEffect(0);
}
```

In async code, you want to avoid forcing code to wait.

EDIT: I fixed my code to use onAnimationEnd.

Comment: Thank you Matthew.What you are proposing me is what i said in my first question "I can use postDelayed(Runnable,miliseconds) and to put all my code in the runnable ,but I am not sure it it the best way to do this".If there are just 2 lines of code - ok,but imagine that there are 3000 lines of code that must be executed after the animation is finished.On each 300 i have another animations and i have to wait them to finish,also.I am still not sure that putting all this code in many delayed runnables is the best way.Unfortunately,it seems that there isn't other way in Android for the code to wait

Comment: @bobi, I actually didn't mean to use `postDelayed`.  That was an oversight when I copied your code.  I would not recommend using a timeout for this.  I meant using [onAnimationEnd](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29) listener.  It really doesn't matter how many lines are afterwards.  You can still have one main method for the 3000 lines, broken into (calling) as many other methods as appropriate.